# How to draw a square using SVG in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, svg

I would like to create a square using SVG in PHP, given two parameters:

Side: (x, y) = e.g: 100;
Corner: (rx, ry) = e.g: 20

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

My code works, but I'm looking for a simplified version ...

Code:

```
  if ($sideOK && $cornerOK){
print " <svg version=\"1.1\" xmlns=\"http:/www.w3.org/2000/svg\"\n"
. " width=\"" .($side+10) ."px\" height=\"" . ($side + 10) . "px\">\n";
print " <rect fill=\"white\" stroke=\"black\" stroke-width=\"10\" "
. "x=\"5\" y=\"5\" width=\"$side\" height=\"$side\" rx=\"$corner\" ry=\"$corner\" />\n";
print " </svg>\n";
print "\n";
```

}

Full code:
Input: form.php> https://pastebin.com/H3PpJgb6
Output: result.php> https://pastebin.com/PGpGJBRN

Any ideas?

Comment: `<svg width="100" height="100"><rect width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);" /></svg>` this is simple html/svg square code. may be help.

Comment: thanks but that's the inline-code i use in html but i haven't gotten it to work in php

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it is "simpler" than what you have, but check out the rectangle function of imagickdraw [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagickdraw.rectangle.php) and [here](https://phpimagick.com/ImagickDraw).